# Streaming in images to Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have around 200 images I need to display one at time in Unity. These need to be held in the application and can't be downloaded from the web.

Right now I have a list set up which takes all of my images and stores. Then, on the hit of a button, I iterate through the list showing each image one at a time. My code looks like this:

```
public static List <Texture2D> images = new List<Texture2D>();

void Start ()
{

    System.Object[] textures = Resources.LoadAll("");
    foreach(object o in textures)
    {
        images.Add(o as Texture2D);
    }

}

public static void MoveForward()
{
    if(_frameCount < images.Count-1)
    {
        _frameCount++;
    }
    else
    {
        _frameCount = 0;
    }
}
```

However, due to the amount of images I need to store, it's eating my iPads memory. I was wondering if there is a better way in which I could do this where I don't need to load each image at run time, hopefully speeding up the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve this problem in two ways:

1) If you need extra responsibility and no loading time, you can put all your assets in one (or more) spritesheets, then load spritesheet and show specific sprites you need. You can optimize memory usage by compressing this sheet.

2) If you can stand a little loading time (or no noticeable delay, if your images are not big) you can load needed image when you click the button, or keep next image preloaded - then you will have only two images loaded at a time. After that, when you move on and don't need some image right now you can unload it by using `Resources.Unload`.

Comment: Depending on image size and how quickly the user is expected to iterate through them (i.e. time per click) a buffer of loaded images with an asynchronous operation to load new ones when the buffer is not full would be the best option, with buffer size depending on the amount of memory you're happy to use in this situation.